# How to show every user specific payment for them in django?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a problem. I have given some random numbers in admin page as a balance for users and connected it to database. Basically I want it to show for different users different payments. But I don't know what to write in `views.py` and `html page` so that it shows different payment for different users.

**models.py**

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    payment_numbers = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**views.py**

```
def payment(request):
    receiving1 = Payment.objects.all()
    for field in receiving1:
        field.payment_numbers
    context = {
        'receiving1': receiving1
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**HTML PAGE**

```
{% for numbers1 in receiving1 %}
    <li style="float: right;">Your Balance: Rs. {{numbers1.payment_numbers}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your models so that payments have a relationship with your users.
A simple way to do that is a ForeignKey to your user model.

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    payment_numbers = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('yourusermodel')
```

Once this is done, you can update your views to pass only the right payments to the context.

```
receiving1 = Payment.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
```

This will of course require you to create new migrations and to ensure your users are properly logged in. Most of this is explained in the [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/)