# How can I show payment update for a specific appointment?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

So I'm trying to make a section under each appointment details that shows their payment transactions of the appointment specifically. all my tries so far didn't work, i can only show all payment updates which is not the wanted result obviously.
this is the code:

views.py the view for updating payments

```
def edit_payment(request, id):
    search_patient_form = SearchPatient()
    current_user_phone = request.session.get('user')
    current_user = get_object_or_404(Doctor, phone = current_user_phone)
    if current_user:
        appointment = get_object_or_404(Appointment, id=id)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = AddAppointmentForm(request.POST)
            searchPatient = SearchPatient(request.POST)
            if searchPatient.is_valid():
                patient_id_phone = searchPatient.cleaned_data['patient_id_phone']
                return redirect('search_patient', id_phone=patient_id_phone)
            elif form.is_valid():
                patient_phone = form.cleaned_data['patient_phone']
                patient = Patient.objects.filter(phone = patient_phone).first()
                doctor_select = form.cleaned_data['doctor_field']
                doctor = Doctor.objects.filter(username = doctor_select).first()
                appointment_date = form.cleaned_data['appointment_date']
                time_slot_field = form.cleaned_data['time_slot_field']
                #time_slot = TimeSlot.objects.filter(slotname=time_slot_field).first()
                appointment_description = form.cleaned_data['appointment_description']
                service_name = form.cleaned_data['service_name']
                total_price = form.cleaned_data['total_price']
                upfront_payment = form.cleaned_data['upfront_payment']
                grand_total = form.cleaned_data['grand_total']
                discount = form.cleaned_data['discount']
                payment_type = form.cleaned_data['payment_type']

                appointment.patient = patient       
                appointment.doctor_of_appointment = doctor      
                appointment.appointment_date = appointment_date
                appointment.receptionist_of_appointment = current_user
                appointment.appointment_timeslot = time_slot_field
                appointment.appointment_description = appointment_description
                appointment.service_name = service_name
                appointment.total_price = total_price
                appointment.upfront_payment = upfront_payment
                appointment.grand_total = grand_total
                appointment.discount = discount
                appointment.payment_type = payment_type
                appointment.save()
                new_log = Log(
                    log_user = current_user,
                    log_descripton = 'Appointment has been editted. {0}'.format(
                    str(id)),
                )
                new_log.save()
                #Payment Update Section 
                new_update = PaymentUpDate(
                    payment_amount = 'Total Price : {0} - Patient Payment: {1} - Balance: {2}'.format(
                        total_price,upfront_payment,grand_total
                    )
                )
                new_update.save()
                return redirect('appointment_details', id=appointment.id)
        else:
            form = AddAppointmentForm(initial={
                'patient_phone' : appointment.patient.phone,
                'doctor_field' : appointment.doctor_of_appointment.username,
                'appointment_date' : appointment.appointment_date,
                'time_slot_field' : appointment.appointment_timeslot,
                'appointment_description' : appointment.appointment_description,
                'service_name': appointment.service_name,
                'total_price': appointment.total_price,
                'upfront_payment': appointment.upfront_payment,
                'grand_total': appointment.grand_total,
                'discount': appointment.discount,
                'payment_type': appointment.payment_type,
            })
        return render(request, 'edit-payment.html', {
            'current_user': current_user,
            'sayfa': 'appointments',
            'form': form,
            'search_patient_form': search_patient_form
        })
    else:
        return redirect('login')
```

the one I'm trying to make it work

```
def appointment_details(request, id):
    search_patient_form = SearchPatient()
    current_user_phone = request.session.get('user')
    current_user = get_object_or_404(Doctor, phone = current_user_phone)
    if current_user:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            searchPatient = SearchPatient(request.POST)
            if searchPatient.is_valid():
                patient_id_phone = searchPatient.cleaned_data['patient_id_phone']
                return redirect('search_patient', id_phone=patient_id_phone)
        else:
            appointment = get_object_or_404(Appointment, id = id)
            updates = PaymentUpDate.objects.all()
            return render(request, 'about-appointment.html', {
                'current_user': current_user,
                'sayfa': 'appointments',
                'appointment': appointment,
                'updates': updates,
                'search_patient_form': search_patient_form
            })
    else:
        return redirect('login')
```

models.py

This is the class the makes the updates

```
class PaymentUpDate(models.Model):
    payment_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    payment_amount = models.CharField(max_length=550)
```

I've tried doing the same approach as I did to show a specific appointment, which is:

```
appointment = get_object_or_404(Appointment, id = id)
```

to the updates, which looked something like :

```
updates = get_object_or_404(PaymentUpDate, id = id)
```

which resulted in the following error :

```
TypeError at /appointment-details/3
'PaymentUpDate' object is not iterable
```

and i also tried this guide: [How to show every user specific payment for them in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57440333/how-to-show-every-user-specific-payment-for-them-in-django), which made my code look like this:

```
class PaymentUpDate(models.Model):
    payment_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    payment_amount = models.CharField(max_length=550, null=True)
    appointment = models.ForeignKey(Appointment, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

views.py

```
updates = PaymentUpDate.objects.filter(appointment=id)
```

which resulted in not getting any updates for some reason.

Comment: Try `updates = PaymentUpDate.objects.filter(appointment=appointment)`

Comment: still not getting any output. the PaymentUpDate does work in showing updates but my issue is showing these updates for their specific appointments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial comment was incorrect.  The answer [Sunderam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17562044/sunderam-dubey) gave is correct.  There is no output because the update is null.  The only place I can see where you actually create a PymentUpDate is:

```py
#Payment Update Section 
    new_update = PaymentUpDate(
                    payment_amount = 'Total Price : {0} - Patient Payment: {1} - Balance: {2}'.format(
                        total_price,upfront_payment,grand_total
                    )
                )
                new_update.save()
```

Here you create a new PaymentUpDate object, but you have not given it an `appointment` field value, so it defaults to null.  Therefore when you search for a PaymentUpDate instance connected to a particular appointment, it returns nothing, no output.

So, change it to:

```py
#Payment Update Section 
new_update = PaymentUpDate(
                    payment_amount = 'Total Price : {0} - Patient Payment: {1} - Balance: {2}'.format(
                        total_price,upfront_payment,grand_total
                    ),
                    appointment=appointment
                )
                new_update.save()
```

You have a lot of `if...elif...else`.  Not criticizing, but if my answer still does not help, try adding `print` statements at various locations in your logic, to see if you are indeed getting to where you want, and if new PaymentUpDate objects are actually being produced.

Answer (score 1):

You can try belew querysets, one of which @raphael already mentioned in above comment.

```py
PaymentUpDate.objects.filter(appointment=appointment)
```

Or:

```py
PaymentUpDate.objects.filter(appointment_id=id)
```

But I seriously think that `...filter(appointment=id)` should also work can you please check whether the `PaymentUpDate` model has the instances of `Appointment` model or not as you have `null=True` in ForeignKey (then I think you should also have `blank=True`).

Comment: i tried your approach and @raphael, which resulted in no output. #Payment Update Section 
                new_update = PaymentUpDate(
                    payment_amount = 'Total Price : {0} - Patient Payment: {1} - Balance: {2}'.format(
                        total_price,upfront_payment,grand_total
                    )
                )
                new_update.save(). this is in the views.py that is making these updates when ever i update the payment for appointment. I'm still confused    here.

Comment: I've added the full code that makes the updates for payment, in which ``` PaymentUpDate ``` is present. can you spare sometime and check it out please.

Comment: You were right, @Sunderam, and my comment was not correct.  I upvoted your answer.  You figured that the issue was with having a null appointment field in PaymentUpDate, and I believe that is correct now that the OP has posted more of the code.